# How can I change the a value of an object in a React state dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here I am having a state in React hook which has an array of multiple objects. Each object has a key named value which stores the sorting value (+ 1 of the previous object):

```js
const [state, setState] = useState([
      {
         value="item1",
         data="..."
      },
      {
         value="item2",
         data="..."
      },
      {
         value="item3",
         data="..."
      },
      {............
])
```

Now my question is how I can set dynamically the value of `value` key if any new object is added either in-between of any previous objects (eg: between index 0 & 1) or at the end or move one of them up/down

Before for the solution I tried to compare the index value and try to set using the `onChange` method but ran into this:

```js
  //qtNumber Handles the numbering, problem is setting them in state
  const SetNumbering = (index, qtNumber) => {
    setState(prevQuestion => {
      return [
        ...prevQuestion.slice(0, CurrentSection),
        {
            ...prevQuestion[CurrentSection],
            value: "item" + qtNumber            
        },
        ...prevQuestion.slice(CurrentSection + 1)
      ];
    });
  };
```

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for, do you either want to generate unique ids or do you want to update an object based on a dynamic key?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking, and the error you described is probably caused by a state updates triggering more state updates, which does not seem related to the question you're asking. It would be useful to see more of your code, what does your solution attempt look like?

Comment: You can sort the array after you add the new value, something like `setState([...state, newValue].sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.value.replace(/\D/g, '') - parseInt(b.value.replace(/\D/g, '')))`

Comment: updated the state logic @EmileBergeron, want in the form of (item & index +1)

Comment: I dont want to sort @Titus

Comment: I want to add a new object or move them so once I do that then `value` should be set automatically with the index position

Comment: Are you saying you want all of the existing members after the new element to have a new `value`? I.e. if you have 3 items and you insert something at the 0th position, then `item1` will become `item2` and so on?

Comment: yup, you got it @rfestag

Comment: This looks like an xy problem. Why would you need this when you can just use the element's index in the array to generate that string on the fly ? Something like `item + (index + 1)`

Comment: @Titus I thought to go with that approach but I need to update all the object value if I move any object up/down. Take an eg: if there are 9 objects and I want to add new to index position of 0 then the new object's value would be `item1` and rest change to `item(n-1)`

Comment: Really, what it sounds like you want is a unique identifier for each object. A library like `nanoid` would let you do that (and control the length of it so it isn't an unnecessarily large uuid, but also having a factory to build your objects that creates a one-up identifier should be sufficient. The actual value of the `value` shouldn't matter if your goal is to use it as a key. It just needs to be unique

Comment: Yes, that is also true for their index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can have all elements after the new element be mapped to new objects with updated `value` fields. I will say, this does seem a bit odd (and may indicate you want to do something different here, it's a bit wasteful). However, this should do what you are asking:

```
  //qtNumber Handles the numbering, problem is setting them in state
  const SetNumbering = (index, qtNumber) => {
    setState(prevQuestion => {
      const before = prevQuestion.slice(0, CurrentSection)
      const after = prevQuestion.slice(CurrentSection + 1).map((q, i) => ({
        value: `item${i+qtNumber+1}`,
        data: q.data
      }))
      return [
        ...before
        {
            ...prevQuestion[CurrentSection],
            value: "item" + qtNumber            
        },
        ...after
      ];
    });
  };
```

Comment: but keys may differ in objects so in that case? like in one object there may other key called `options`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean here. Nowhere in the model you show above is there an "options". If you are referring to your `data` string, those are passed through. If your objects have different keys, use something like `{...q, value: \`items${i+qtNumber+1}\`}`

Comment: is there any way that we can update numbering all objects in more than 1 array?